# Вопрос по исправлении ошибок HTML

Tags: html, dom

Слушайте ребят, я слышал, что браузер может неправильный HTML код интерпретировать как правильный, допустим забыл один закрывающий тег, — браузер его добавил. Есть ли какие-нибудь документы, которые рассказывают о критериях, когда браузер будет исправлять этот код, а когда нет? Допустим "В такой-то такой-то ситуации, если не будет вот тут и тут такой-то буквы, то браузер посчитает это за незначительную ошибку и самостоятельно исправит ее". Буду благодарен, если подскажете.

```
Пример:

    1) 
    --> <a//href='/'>
        <a href='/'> <--
    
    2)
    --> <p>123</>
        <p>123</p> <--
```

Comment: все браузеры разные и могут по разному обрабатывать не соответствие спецификации

Comment: Не проще ли не допускать таких ошибок? Сейчас есть много сервисов и плагинов для валидации кода, при работе с автокомплитом никогда не было таких проблем и даже вопросов не возникало. Это я не говорю про сборщики, которые и на ошибку тыкнут прямо в разработке.

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#an-introduction-to-error-handling-and-strange-cases-in-the-parser

Comment: Мне больше всего нравится подход в XHTML-режиме: если есть хоть одна мелкая синтаксическая ошибочка, браузер откажется показывать страницу целиком и полностью :) Жаль только, что XHTML никто нынче не использует